# "moveRowAtIndexPath" is called if I select a row or move a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to detect between `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `moveRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView` button but i figure out that when i set `[myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]` at `ViewDidLoad` then whether i select or move on cell it always into  `moveRowAtIndexPath`. I really want to detect two this methods to have different treatments when tap or move on cell.

this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [HomeTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [HomeTableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    //it's always get here when i select on cell
    //do something here
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) // Don't move the first row
    {
        return NO;
    }
        return YES;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //i wanna do thing here but it's never into this method when i set [HomeTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of UITableView to true..

```
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property on `UITableView` which allows to select rows in editing mode. You can set it in `storyboard` to `Single Selection During Editing` or in code set the `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property to `YES`.